# Error on trying to convert a python file into an executable with cx_freeze

Tags: python, pyqt, cx-freeze

I've got code with PyQt:

```
import sys

from PyQt4.QtGui import *
from PyQt4.QtCore import *
from PyQt4.QtWebKit import *

def main():
    page = raw_input('Escriu una web: ')
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    view = QWebView()
    view.settings().setAttribute(QWebSettings.JavascriptEnabled, True)
    view.load(QUrl(page))
    view.setWindowTitle('Titanicus 0.1')
    view.show()
    app.exec_()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

And my setup.py file is this:

```
    import sys
    from cx_Freeze import setup, Executable

    setup(
        name = "On Dijkstra's Algorithm",
        version = "3.1",
        description = "A Dijkstra's Algorithm help tool.",
        executables = [Executable("nautilus.py")])
```

I've the folder build but when I try to open th new exe file it returns me that error:

```
File "ExtensionLoader_PyQt4_QtGui.py", line 11, in <module>
ImportError: No module named atexit
```

Help please!

Answer (score 0):

I'd try adding `options = {"build_exe" : {"includes" : "atexit" }}` to `setup.py`,

ref. https://bitbucket.org/reclosedev/cx_freeze/src/f3cacc2fd45a/samples/PyQt4/setup.py

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
#-*- coding:utf-8 -*-

from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore, QtWebKit, QtNetwork

class myWindow(QtWebKit.QWebView):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(myWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setWindowTitle('Titanicus 0.1')
        self.settings().setAttribute(QtWebKit.QWebSettings.JavascriptEnabled, True)

        page = raw_input('Escriu una web: ')
        self.load(QtCore.QUrl(page))

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import  sys

    app  = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    main = myWindow()
    main.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Yes good, this way of code is better but it returns an EOFError in the input line. Why?

Comment: How did you install cx_freeze? If you installed it via pip or easy_install, remove it with `pip remove cx_freeze` download the source [from here](http://freefr.dl.sourceforge.net/project/cx-freeze/4.3.1/cx_Freeze-4.3.1.tar.gz) and follow the `readme` instructions to install it